# SVG Matching stroke-dashoffset from two different paths

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have two different paths where I'm animating the stroke-dashoffset, which gives the drawing effect. There's two buttons that increase/decrease the stroke-dashoffset.

What I'm trying to achieve is by matching the filled paths aligned vertically throughout the whole progression. Is this even possible?

[image]

Currently in the demo, the stroke-dashoffsets from both paths don't match since the jagged path has greater length.

I would like the avoid the solution where it involves placing a main path on top of the other two, since it would get rid of the "drawing" animation look on the jagged line and both paths have rounded ends.

```js
const btnAdd = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
const btnSub = document.querySelector(".btn-sub");
const line = document.querySelector(".line");
const jaggedLine = document.querySelector(".jagged-line");
const lineLength = line.getTotalLength();
const jaggedLineLength = jaggedLine.getTotalLength();

line.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", lineLength);
jaggedLine.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", jaggedLineLength);
line.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", lineLength);
jaggedLine.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", jaggedLineLength);

let progress = 0;

const updateSVG = () => {
  line.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", lineLength - progress);
  jaggedLine.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", jaggedLineLength - progress);
};
btnAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
  progress++;
  updateSVG();
});
btnSub.addEventListener("click", () => {
  progress--;
  updateSVG();
});
```

```css
.svg {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
  <button class="btn-add">+</button>
  <button class="btn-sub">-</button>
  <div class="svg">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715" height="172.781" width="278.7779">
      <g fill="none" stroke="#00aad4" stroke-linecap="round">
        <path
          d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
          opacity=".165" stroke-width=".965" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <path d="M.8825.8825h71.995" opacity=".1648" stroke-width=".965" />
        <path class="jagged-line"
          d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
          stroke-width="1.765" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <path class="line" d="M.8825.8825h71.995" stroke-width="1.765" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: Compositing a single rect atop these pathes sounds like the easiest way, though the rounded linecap would be troublesome...

Comment: One ugly solution is to spam getPointAtLength until its `x` matches `progress`: https://jsfiddle.net/o8p5u3za/

Comment: @Kaiido Ugly as in, it's not ideal in performance? I think using requestAnimationFrame instead of the while loop could alleviate blocking the main thread. So far your solution is the best, thanks :)

Comment: Ugly as in not very dynamic. For instance it assumes the animation only goes on x axis, if one day you decide to rotate it, the whole code would break. Performance wise that should be fine.

Comment: Use the x value of the jagged line point and apply it to the straight line stroke-dasharray, the straight line will move slower than the jagged line

Answer (score 2):

There is an SVG attribute `pathLength` which allows us to **set** the path length.

> The pathLength attribute lets authors specify a total length for the path, in user units. This value is then used to calibrate the browser's distance calculations with those of the author, by scaling all distance computations using the ratio pathLength/(computed value of path length).
>
> This can affect the actual rendered lengths of paths; including text paths, animation paths, and various stroke operations. Basically, all computations that require the length of the path. stroke-dasharray, for example, will assume the start of the path being 0 and the end point the value defined in the pathLength attribute.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength)

If we set the same `pathLength` to both the animation become simple.

```css
.svg {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

.line,
.jagged-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715" height="172.781" width="278.7779">
      <g fill="none" stroke="#00aad4" stroke-linecap="round">
        <path
          d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
          opacity=".165" stroke-width=".965" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <path d="M.8825.8825h71.995" opacity=".1648" stroke-width=".965" />
        <path class="jagged-line"
          d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
          stroke-width="1.765" stroke-linejoin="round" pathLength="100"/>
        <path class="line" d="M.8825.8825h71.995" stroke-width="1.765" pathLength="100"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: So close, but it's inconsistent at certain parts of the progression. I need them to be equal length throughout the whole progress.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean...the paths are the same length. I suspect you mean that you want the filled parts to align vertically and that's a whole other issue and a lot more complicated since the animation would not be linear.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have said equal length. You worded it perfectly, I wanted the filled paths aligned vertically throughout the whole progression. So far @Kaiido was able to solve my question using getPointAtLength attribute, even though it uses a while loop to continually check it. Thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: You could break up the straight line into the same number of path segments as the jagged line and then give each straight segment the same pathLength as the jagged line that is its twin.

Comment: @RobertLongson so the straight line has to have the same amount of nodes as jagged line? Or actually broken into separate path elements. Here's a demo showing two different straight lines, one with two nodes, the other other with same node amount as jagged line, but there's no difference. https://jsfiddle.net/Lishipu/jwoLr1h9/8/